# Is it possible to call C# code from a Protractor test?

Tags: c#, angularjs, unit-testing, protractor

I would like to use C# to implement part of my Protractor unit tests. Is this possible?

The reason for this is that I want to extract some data from my DB and compare it to the expected results which are stored in text files. There's too much heavy lifting involved to do this in JavaScript. So, I would like to invoke a C# DLL or EXE to do this part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with [Edge.js](http://tjanczuk.github.io/edge/#/)

Ultimately Protractor is running inside a node process, and therefore anything you can do with node, you can do with Protractor.

You just need to install edge:

`npm install edge -g`

And then require it and do something with .Net code inside your spec file:

```
var edge = require('edge');

var hello = edge.func(function () {/*
 async (input) => {
 return "CSharp welcomes " + input.ToString();
 }
 */});

describe('.Net is in your node!', function(){

  beforeEach(function(){
    hello('Node.js', function (error, result) {
      if (error) throw error;
      console.log(result);
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: didn't know about that project! +1 for the reference!